# Replace the fragment then press back fast cause UI delayed response, shadows and corners effect are disappeared

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I faced a very stranger problem. My situation is:

I built an application contain many pages, each page is a `Fragment`. And i used `RecyclerView` and `CardView` inside each page. My **home page's** layout look like:

[image]

When i click on a image item to navigate to **detail page** then press back button right after that, my home page is show up but:

[image]

As you can see, all **shadow and corner effect disappeared**, scroll didn't work, when i touch an item it take a **few second before navigate detail page**. When detail page shown, every things back to normal. Here is my replace fragment method:

```
public void replaceBackgroundFragment(Fragment mf, String tag, boolean addBackStack) {
    if (mf != null && (currentFragmentTag == null || !currentFragmentTag.equals(tag))) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left,
                R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
        ft.replace(R.id.rl_background, mf, tag);
        if (addBackStack) {
            mf.setCanBack(true);
            ft.addToBackStack(tag);
        }
        ft.commit();
        pendingFragment = null;
        pendingTag = null;
    }
}
```

When click on an item:

```
public void onItemClick(MainBanner item) {
      MoviePlayerFragment fragment = MoviePlayerFragment.newInstance(item.getItemID());
      activity.replaceBackgroundFragment(fragment, "movie_player_fragment" + item.getItemID(), true);
}
```

**EDIT**
I used `setRetainInstance(true);` in my `Fragment`

**Can anybody let me know what is happening?**

Comment: I don't see a problem with the posted code. Perhaps it's code elsewhere or the layout(s).

Comment: @TheOriginalAndroid there are all of code that impact the fragment transition. I used `setRetainInstance(true)` on the `Fragment`. I think it can be a `CardView` bug.

Comment: @mr.icetea happening on which version of android?

Comment: @Raghunandan android 5.0.2

Answer (score 0):

you may use ft.add(R.id.rl_background, mf, tag); instead of ft.replace(R.id.rl_background, mf, tag);

Comment: I don't want to add fragment.